# Trying to figure out how to insert a string into a struct

Tags: arrays, c, string, struct

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct example{
    char message[10];
};
char x[10];
int main(){
    scanf("%s",&x);
    struct example M={x};
    printf("%s",M.message);
    return 0;
}
```

Line 8 Col 24 [Error] array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer

(run)

Expected: message that the user has inserted appears

Result: error, despite x being in braces {}

Comment: You problem is that the array `x`, in many situations, gets converted to a pointer to its first element. That happens in the initialization `struct example M = {x};`. The compiler assumes you want to initialize `M.message[0]` with the value `x` (and `M.message[1]` etc to `0`). Your best option would be to simply define the object `struct example M;` and then do `strcpy(M.message, x);`